# Two Sum Leetcode in Javascript - code looks correct but Leetcode says it's wrong

Tags: javascript

I'm working on the ['Two Sum' problem in Leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum).

I'm sure this code is correct, I've tested it in Repl and it looks correct there, but Leetcode is giving me an error.

Here's my code:

```
var arr = [];

var twoSum = function(nums, target) {
   for(var i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){
        for(var j = i+1; j < nums.length; j++){
            console.log(nums[i] + ', ' + nums[j]);
            var tot = nums[i] + nums[j];        
            if(tot === target){
                arr.push(i,j);
                console.log(arr);
                return arr;
            }     
         }         
   }
};

//var a = [2, 7, 11, 15];
//var b = 9;
var a = [2, 3, 4];
var b = 6;

twoSum(a, b);
```

The error I'm getting is as follows:

```
Input:
[3,2,4]
6
Output:
[0,1,1,2]
Expected:
[1,2]
```

Why is it expecting `[1, 2]`? Surely it should expect `[0, 1]` in this case, and then why is my code adding to the arr array twice?  It looks like a bug to me...

Note: I see there's many posts about this problem on Leetcode, but none address the specific issue I have run into in Javascript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why is it expecting [1, 2]?

Because 2 + 4 = 6

> Surely it should expect [0, 1] in this case

No, because 3 + 2 = 5

> and then why is my code adding to the arr array twice?

Because you declared the array outside of the function. It is being re-used for every call to the function. Move the array declaration into your `twoSum` function or even better: Simply `return [i, j]` instead of `push`ing into the empty array.

Comment: Thank you, moving the array inside the function fixed it. I love dyslexia, for some reason my brain had decided I needed to find the product not the sum, and was doing something bizarre with that. Hrrumff.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution you can try...

```
var twoSum = function(nums, target) {
let map = {};
for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
  let compliment = target - nums[i];
  if (map[compliment]) {
    return [(map[compliment] - 1), i];
  } else {
    map[nums[i]] = i + 1;
    }
   }
 };

 twoSum([2, 3, 4],6);
```

[Click Here to RUN](https://repl.it/@jaymanale/TwoSum)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an optimum solution

```js
/**
 * @param {number[]} nums
 * @param {number} target
 * @return {number[]}
 */
function twoSum(nums, target) {
  const numsObjs = {}; // create nums obj with value as key and index as value eg: [2,7,11,15] => {2: 0, 7: 1, 11: 2, 15: 3}

  for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    const currentValue = nums[i];

    if (target - currentValue in numsObjs) {
      return [i, numsObjs[target - currentValue]];
    }
    numsObjs[nums[i]] = i;
  }

  return [-1, -1];
}

console.log(twoSum([2, 7, 11, 15], 9))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution, which is a brute force method that uses javascript to search for all possible pairs of numbers.

```js
var twoSum = function(nums, target) {
    let numarray = new Array(2);
    for (var i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        for (var j = i + 1; j < nums.length; j++) {
            if (nums[i] + nums[j] == target) {
                numarray[0] = i;
                numarray[1] = j;
            }
        }

    }
    return numarray;

};
```